# How to add a User Agent to the SoapClient generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: web-services, soap, user-agent

I'm trying to invoke a webservice using the classes generated by Visual Studio in an ASP MVC project, here is my code:

```
var serviceClient = new UserSoapClient("UserSoap");

var isValid = serviceClient.CheckEmail(email);
ViewBag.ServiceOutput = isValid? "Email is valid" : "Email is not valid";
return View();
```

However, the message is timing out and it seems that the problem is that the request header of the SoapClient is not sending the User-Agent property because I tried executing the same service with SOAP UI and that was the only difference. Is there any way of setting the User Agent because I'm looking at the documentation and it doesn't seem to be very obvious.

Comment: Did you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Yes, UserSoapClient is the class generated by AddServicereference that contains the calls to the web services methods

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with a similar problem while trying to consume a service with *SoapClient*. I was able to get response from the service via browser but when I execute the code within the project service was returning *Protocol Exception* with *The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.* message.

After several hours of tracing I have realised that the Exception was caused by the user-agent  definition. I have tried to add user-agent to the Soap request header but no way. You can not add user-agent to Soap request registered as Service Reference. But it is possible to define user-agent header to a request registered as Web Service Reference.

What my solution is:

1. Remove the Service Reference from the project
2. Add the same reference as Web Reference from the advanced menu of Add Service Reference Window
3. Create a new object and define UserAgent property like below.

   ```
   var svc = new ServiceReference.QueryService();
   svc.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36";
   ```